# unknown type name 'class' in a nested class using templates

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class

I am having an issue with my nested class. The file uses template classes to implement a queue but has a compile error that I cannot understand. My personal research into the error shows that it has something to do with the declaration of the template valuename but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the source code for the class: queue.h

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

template<class T>
class Queue
{
private:
    template<class U>
    class Node
    {
    private:
        U _item;
        Node* _next;
    public:
        Node(U item);
        ~Node();
        U getItem();
        Node<U>* getNext();
        void setNext(Node<U>* next);
    };
    unsigned _size;
    Node<T>* _head;
    Node<T>* _tail;

public:
    Queue();
    ~Queue();
    Node<T>* getHead();
    Node<T>* getTail();
    unsigned size();
    bool isEmpty();
    void push_back(T item);
    T pop();
    void combine(Queue<T> qu);
};

//////////////////////////////////
//NODE
//////////////////////////////////
template<class T>
template<class U>
Queue<T>::Node<U>::Node(U item)
//constructor
{
    _item = item;
    _next = NULL;
}

template<class T>
template<class U>
Queue<T>::Node<U>::~Node()
//destructor
{
}

template<class T>
template<class U>
U Queue<T>::Node<U>::getItem()
//returns the provided item.
{
    return _item;
}

template<class T>
template<class U>
Node<U>* Queue<T>::Node<U>::getNext()
//returns a pointer to the next node in the queue.
{
    return _next;
}

template<class T>
template<class U>
void Queue<T>::Node<U>::setNext(Node<U>* next)
//sets the next node in the queue to the provided Node
{
    _next = next;
}
//////////////////////////////////
//QUEUE
//////////////////////////////////
template<class T>
Queue<T>::Queue()
//constructor
{
    _size = 0;
    _head = NULL;
    _tail = NULL;
}

template<class T>
Queue<T>::~Queue()
//destructor
{
    while(!isEmpty()){
        pop();
    }
}

template<class T>
Node<T>* Queue<T>::getHead()
//returns the node at the front of the queue
{
    return _head;
}

template<class T>
Node<T>* Queue<T>::getTail()
//returns the node at the end of the queue
{
    return _tail;
}

template<class T>
unsigned Queue<T>::size()
//returns the size of the queue
{
    return _size;
}

template<class T>
bool Queue<T>::isEmpty()
//if the queue is empty return true, otherwise return false
{
    if(_size == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<class T>
void Queue<T>::push_back(<T> item)
//add a node to the back of the queue with the provided data item
{
    Node<T>* nnode = new Node<T>(item);
    if(_head == NULL){
        _head = nnode;
        _tail = nnode;
    }
    _tail.setNext(nnode);
    _tail = nnode;
    _size++;
}

template<class T>
T Queue<T>::pop()
//removes the value at the front of the queue and returns it
{
        Node<T>* cur = _head;
        _head = cur->getNext();
        _size--;
        <T> item = cur.getItem();
        delete cur;
        return item;
}

template<class T>
void Queue<T>::combine(Queue<T> qu)
//adds the provided queue to the end of the current queue
{
    _tail.setNext(qu.getHead());
    _tail = qu.getTail();
    _size+= qu.size();
}

#endif
```

The error I receive is:

```
./queue.h:63:1: error: unknown type name 'Node'
Node<U>* Queue<T>::Node<U>::getNext()
^
./queue.h:63:5: error: expected unqualified-id
Node<U>* Queue<T>::Node<U>::getNext()
    ^
```

If you have any suggestions I would be glad to hear them.

Comment: `<T> item` in the definition of `Queue::push_back` should be just `T item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
Node<U>* Queue<T>::Node<U>::getNext()
```

into:

```
typename Queue<T>::template Node<U>* Queue<T>::Node<U>::getNext()
```

and others as well:

```
Node<T>* Queue<T>::getHead()
```

into:

```
typename Queue<T>::template Node<T>* Queue<T>::getHead()
```

as well as this *strange*:

```
void Queue<T>::push_back(<T> item)
```

into:

```
void Queue<T>::push_back(T item)
```

and last but not least:

```
T item = cur.getItem();
```

into:

```
T item = cur->getItem();
```

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) nested types do not need a scope if they are specified in a trailing return type, so instead:

```
typename Queue<T>::template Node<U>* Queue<T>::Node<U>::getNext()
```

you can just say:

```
auto Queue<T>::Node<U>::getNext() -> Node<U>*
```

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) just say `auto` and shorten your original declaration by half:

```
auto Queue<T>::Node<U>::getNext()
```